# cassandra bootstrap fail with "Streaming error occurred"

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster in aws ec2. the cluster has 7 nodes now. and I want to add a new node to this cluster. but there is error occured with bootstrap. the bootstrap can not finish sucessfully.

I got many kinds of errors:

```
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/172.31.20.223] 2016-01-01 15:37:30,941 StreamSession.java:524 - [Stream #b1cc3600-b054-11e5-80c4-21d1c7c11a01] Streaming error occurred:
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:257) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:300) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:53) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
```

also error like this:

```
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.20.223] 2016-01-01 15:37:30,941 StreamSession.java:644 - [Stream #b1cc3600-b054-11e5-80
c4-21d1c7c11a01] Retrying for following error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Last written key DecoratedKey(-8466153190082758358, 000000000000356a) >= current key
 DecoratedKey(-9223372036854775808, ) writing into /data_lvm/cassandra/data/feeds/inbox-eb873af0a19711e5ade0432b
31304f95/tmp-la-309-big-Data.db
```

also errors like this:

```
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.8.188] 2016-01-01 15:25:05,001 StreamSession.java:644 - [Stream #b1cc3600-b054-11e5-80c4-21d1c7c11a01] Retrying for following error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough bytes
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType.checkRemaining(AbstractCType.java:362) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCompoundCellNameType.fromByteBuffer(AbstractCompoundCellNa
meType.java:98) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:381) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
```

and also erros like this:

```
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.4.135] 2016-01-01 15:23:44,228 StreamSession.java:644 - [Stream #b1cc3600-b054-11e5-80c
4-21d1c7c11a01] Retrying for following error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
ERROR [Thread-571] 2016-01-01 15:23:44,228 CassandraDaemon.java:185 - Exception in thread Thread[Thread-571,5,ma
in]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:
2.2.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
.java:1220) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream$Reader.runMayThrow(CompressedInputStrea
m.java:176) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:
2.2.4]
```

I tried many things to bootstrap, like cleanuped all nodes, scrubed all nodes, repaired all nodes. but It still fails with error.

can anyone help to find out what's the problem?

I startup the cluster with 6 nodes, and added the 7th node successfully. but when I try to add 8th node, it fails.

every nodes has about 500G data.

I use DataStax Community Edition 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that release 2.2.4 has a problem when adding nodes to an existing cluster.

Checkout this jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10961

I had the same problem and used the patched jar and worked.

Fix will be officially released on 2.2.5 version. But you can use this path in the mean time.